# How to edit/save changes in GridView with Object Data Source?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have my own object class which I use as the data source for gridview.  I am binding the columns to class properties which display perfectly fine.  However it does not save on edit.  I am wondering how do I save changes from Gridview?  Specifically is there anyway to call the SET method in my class properties?  Here is some code snipit:

Note:  I am using my object directly as the datasource, and not through the ObjectDataSource interface.  So I can't use the updateMethod.

Binding:

```
   <asp:TextBox ID="txb_customerName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("customerName") %>' />
```

Object Property:

```
    public string customerName
    {
        get
        {
            if (!_loaded) { load(); }
            return _customerName;
        }
        set { _customerName = value; }
    }
```

Comment: Save changes to "state" or save changes to database?

Comment: Ultimately to database.  I can do the saving, if the object class can get the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the updatemethod property of the object datasource (see link). The update method is the name of the method you use to update/save the record in the class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.updatemethod.aspx

Comment: But I am using my object directly without it going through a object datasource.

Comment: I believe you will have to programmatically set the value back to the class and then call the update procedure manually.

Comment: Yea that's what I ended up doing, it's inconvinent, but at least the code is very object oriented now.

Comment: Object-oriented...loving it. :)